# Entity Framework - Modelleing Many-to-Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to model a second-level many-to-many (a 'many-to-many-to-many') relationship in `Entity Framework 6 Code-First`.

I have two reference classes called `Preferences` and `SubPreferences`, i.e. each `Preference` will define one or more `Sub-Preferences`.

```
public class Preference
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name get; set; }

    // Navigation
    public virtual ICollection<SubPreference> SubPrefeences { get; set; }
} 

public class SubPreference
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PreferenceId { get; set; }
    public string Name get; set; }

    // Navigation
    public virtual Preference Prefeences { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a `User` class.  Each `User` can select/be assigned one or more `Preferences`:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    // Navigation
    public virtual ICollection<Preferences> Preferences { get; set; }
}
```

In the Data Context this is mapped as follows:

```
public class UserMap
    : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        ToTable("Users");

        // Primary Key
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        Property(u => u.Id).IsRequired().HasColumnName("Id");
        Property(u => u.Email).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256).HasColumnName("Email");
        HasMany(u => u.Preferences)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                x.MapRightKey("PreferenceId");
                x.ToTable("UserPreferences");
            });
    }
}
```

This uses the following many-to-many SQL link table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserPreferences] (
    [UserId]         INT NOT NULL,
    [PreferenceId]   INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.UserPreferences]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC, [PreferenceId] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.UserPreferences_dbo.Users_Id]
        FOREIGN KEY ([UserId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([Id])
        ON DELETE CASCADE

    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.UserPreferences_dbo.Preferences_Id]
        FOREIGN KEY ([PreferenceId]) 
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Preferences] ([Id])
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
);
```

The `User` can then manage their preferences by selecting one or more `Preference` check-boxes on the user interface (UI).  All of this works as expected.

The requirement has now changed so that the `User` can not only select their Preferences, but also be able to refine those `Preferences` by `SubPreference`.  From a UI perspective, the user would check a `Preference` and then a list of check-boxes would be revealed for the `SubPreferences` for the selected `Preference`.

In effect, this would create a *many-to-many-to-many* relationship.  Is it possible to model this type of relationship in Entity Framework by extending the code above, or would I need to build formal objects/classes to define the relationships?

I should mention that I am unable to change the existing table structures as they are also used by older applications within the suite.

Comment: Probably I did not understand, anyway, SubPreference has an Id field that is primary key. You can map it on user exactly as you did for Preference. Is a problem of the UI to show a nice tree using SubPreference.Preference property.  Also, if the user can only select subpreferences you could delete Preferences from the user and insert only SubPreferences. Also in this case is the UI that should manage a "Select All" on SubPreferences when you click on a Preference

Comment: This is possible, but existing users are already assigned to one or more Preferences (but no SubPreferences).  I could, I suppose, create a script that assigns Preference only users to all of the SubPreferences within their selected Preferences to achieve the data that I would need to make this work.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here is my opinion:

`Preference` and `SubPreference` are practically the same thing. So, only the model `Preference` using self relationship should be enough. `Preference` may have many `Preference` and may also have a "parent" `Preference`. Like this:

```
public class Preference
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Preference Parent { get; set; }

    // Navigation
    public virtual ICollection<Preference> SubPreferences { get; set; }
}
```

Then, the `User` mapping would be something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Preference>()
    .HasOptional(i => i.ParentPreference)
    .WithMany(i => i.SubPreferences)
    .HasForeignKey(i => i.ParentId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Preferences)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(x =>
    {
        x.MapLeftKey("UserId");
        x.MapRightKey("PreferenceId");
        x.ToTable("UserPreferences");
    });
```

Now, `User` is related with `Preference`, that `Preference` might be a "subPreference" or not.

I believe it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you Fabio for taking the time to create this.  My only problem is that that the database is actually used by other applications so I am not readily able to restructure the existing tables.  If I could, your solution is indeed elegant and would be the accepted answer, as it is, I have +1'd it.

Comment: I see, I'll try find in another solution when I get home

Comment: Thank you and apologies for not making the constraints clear in the original question.